# MYSQL query to select from two tables simultanously given a dataset only available in one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, **user** and **userfield**

I wanted to select a few datapoint from both tables, searching based on the **username** field in the **user** table.  The **user** table also contains a **userid**, and so subsequently there are a few datapoints I wanted to extract from the **userfield** table using the **userid** datapoint

Here is an example of the data

***Table: User***

++ user ++ userid ++ avatar

++ Mark ++ 12345 ++ 15

++ John ++ 54321 ++ 25

***Table: Userfield***

++ userid ++ location++ sex

++ 12345 ++ USA ++ Male

++ 54321 ++ Canada ++ Male

Is it possible to select the *user, userid and location* at the same time with a single query **based on only a provided username**?

Tahnks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a very simple SQL concept call the the JOIN.  You want to join the two tables on the userid field:

```
SELECT user, avatar, location, sex
FROM User JOIN Userfield USING (userid)
```

This will select all columns from both tables where the userids match.

To filter by particular usernames, use a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE user = 'Mark'
WHERE user IN ('Mark', 'John')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this all you're looking for -- a basic `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT *
FROM User U 
   INNER JOIN UserField UF ON U.UserId = UF.UserId
WHERE U.User = 'UserName'
```